# Symfony2 GenerateUrl with annotation

Tags: php, symfony

For some reason, i cannot generate the route i have specified for my form builder.

As you see, i specify generateUrl('/login'), but, during form building, the error "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/login" as such route does not exist. ".

Route /login is declared below using annotation, what seems to be the issue? my App controller is set to use annotation.

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction() {

    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('/login'))
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('username', 'text')
            ->add('password', 'text')
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

    $content = $this->renderView('ThisBundleBundle:Login:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

    return new Response($content);
}

/**
 * @Route("/login")
 * @Template()
 */
public function loginAction() {



}
```

routing.yml in the app:

bill_ThisBundleBundle:
    resource: "@ThisBundleBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

Comment: you can use $this->generateUrl('bill_this_controller_login'), where bill is src folder, this is bundle name, controller is name of your controller and login is action name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the name of route like

```
@Route("/", name="some_route_name")
```

and then generate url `$this->generateUrl('some_route_name')`. Or find your route with command `php app/console router:debug` and see internal route name.